# .net 4.0 and IIS get 401.2 error

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, iis-7, .net-4.0

I'm trying to install and configure  .Net 4.0 with IIS 7.5 on a Server 2008 R2 machine.  IIS is configured for anonymous authentication.  When I load http://localhost, I get 401.2.  The site is defaulting to use the 'defaultapppool' and this app pool is configured to use .Net 4.0 as the managed code.

If i changed the managed code to .Net 2.0, http://localhost loads up just fine.  This only errors when using .Net 4.0.  I've tried changing the app pool service account and even repaired .Net, but can't seem to get around the 401.2 error.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: The Application Pool identity has to be able to read the files. Make sure it matches the file system file security. What is the identity set to for the defaultapppool?

Comment: identity is 'apppoolidentity' (default), but I have tried assigning the identity to a domain admin account and it still fails.   I've gone as far as using Procmon to see any file access violations, but found none.

Comment: Had to remove and reinstall IIS and .Net 4.0 completely. Not sure why this was the case and I have no idea what was originally broken.  In the future, I found this article: 

http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/07/26/Troubleshoot-IIS7-errors-like-a-pro.aspx

This may be useful for anyone else who sees problems here.  By the time I found this, I had already finished the R&R. 

Thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: If reinstalling .Net 4.0 fixed it, it may have been due to your install order so that .Net wasn't registered with IIS completely correctly. For future reference, there is a reg_iis.exe utility with .Net that can fix that problem without a reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, click on "Convert to Application". Add permissions to project folder for "Network Service".

Comment: the project folder is the IIS root directory.  No application has even been installed, as of yet.  Further, Network service is no longer the default account that manages .net applications in IIS 7.x.  It defaults to 'apppoolidentity' whereas IIS 6 used Network Service.  In any case, i did try this in the past. Right now, I'm doing a complete removal and reinstall of IIS and .Net.

Comment: In IIS, did you check the authentication is correct (Authentication) icon? Sometimes I have to do this manually, or is there a conflict with a Web.Config entry? Failing that a reinstall may be best.

Comment: Had to remove and reinstall IIS and .Net 4.0 completely. Not sure why this was the case and I have no idea what was originally broken.  In the future, I found this article: 

http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/07/26/Troubleshoot-IIS7-errors-like-a-pro.aspx

This may be useful for anyone else who sees problems here.  By the time I found this, I had already finished the R&R. 

Thanks everyone for your input.